# Can you help me understand the following sentence?

Tags: translation, sentence

> その中には巨体の芳江が泡を吹いてノビている姿もある。

I got the above sentence from a short story that goes like this: a gymnastics club made up of high school girls is ordered by the student council to attack one high school girl who is a member of the Comic Book Club. This girl has proven to be more than a match for them and knocked out more than 10 of them.

I can figure out parts of the sentence.

- その中には has the meaning of “among them”. In this case, “among the girls who have been knocked out”.
- 巨体の芳江 seems to have the meaning of “big-bodied Yoshie”. Regrettably, the story does not provide how to read her name, so I am just guessing. What is clear to me is that the sentence is talking about a club member who has a bigger body than the others.
- 泡を吹いて has the literal meaning of “blowing bubbles”, but the picture that comes with the story indicates that the meaning is closer to “frothing”, that is to say, drooling.
- ノビている seems to be a slang form of 伸びる, and I am not sure if it is referring to her “stretching out” or “passing out”.
- 姿もある might have a meaning like “even has a figure” or “there is also an aspect”. There might be some other meaning that I missed.

Right now, I think the sentence is translated into English as follows:

> Among them, big-bodied Yoshie is frothing and even has a figure that has passed out.

I don't know if that's exactly right. Please tell me if I'm right or wrong. If I'm wrong, please tell me what a better translation might be.

Comment: You got the right meaning. Among the 10 you can see Yoshie, who is a huge person. She is passed out and foaming at the mouth. Here 「泡を吹く」＝苦しんだり、しゃべりたてたりなどして、口から泡を出すさま（https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%B3%A1%E3%82%92%E5%90%B9%E3%81%8F-2004242）、「伸びる」＝さんざんなぐられて動けなくなってしまう（https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BC%B8%E3%81%B3%E3%82%8B-597202）、and 「姿」＝目に見える、人の形（https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%A7%BF-515242）.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This 姿 is modified by 芳江が泡を吹いてノビている, not ノビている alone. 姿 means "figure/picture/appearance", but it's often omitted when translated into English.
- This 姿もある is simply "there is a 姿, too". The topic of your sentence is その中(に), which cannot "have" a thing. (A sentence like 彼女には夢がある is usually translated like "She has a dream", but it's literally "Within her, there is a dream".)
- ノビる means "to stretch out on the floor after being beaten or exhausted". A person who is ノビている is at least groggy, but may not be completely unconscious.
- The reading of 芳江 is almost certainly Yoshie.

So my attempt is "Among them was big-bodied Yoshie, frothing and lying flat on the floor".

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I guess I was thrown off by the 姿もある part of the sentence. Well, at least I was on the right track. (Relieved)